# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json

Tags: jquery, json, vimeo

I have followed intructions to get json data from vimeo with the follwoing code:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/album/' + vimeoId + '/info.json?callback=?', {
            format: "json",
            }, function(data) {
                        // function
                        });
```

But I get this warning in chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   application/json.

I found a few post with solutions but non seemed to remove the error.

Any advise on this will be much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug on Vimeo's side.  It's [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works), which is really a script, so it should be a script MIME type such as `application/javascript` or `text/javascript`.